# If a class implements serializable interface then is its child class also serialize or not?

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization

[`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) is a marker interface . If a class A implements `Serializable` and the other class B & C extend  A, then are they both get serialize even if there's no method to implement?

Comment: Yes it will get serialied

Comment: Those are the rules of Java. Nothing special about the Serializable interface in that respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Serializable` interface does nothing by itself, it is merely, as you remarked, a marker interface to show Java that this particular class is serializable. That means that if you denote a class with this interface, all child classes will be treated as serializable by themselves (just like normal inheritance), but the task of a successfully serialization must be ensured by you, as you control which fields your classes contain - and every field whose type does not implement `Serializable` will break the contract.